# How can I blacken a brown pair of boots? Will black shoe polish work as I'd intend?

Tags: clothing

I am hoping to go to a community where black clothing is preferred (but not mandatory). My best pair of boots is a polished brown, which I would like to turn to black.

I wanted to check in about how to do this with cheaply/easily acquired items.

How well or poorly would thoroughly polishing the exterior with black shoe polish work?

Are there are other materials or approaches that would make sense?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to go to a leather store or a shoe repair and tell them
what you are trying to do. No home job here! This is for the experts.
If you love your boots, a few dollars won't hurt.
Happy hunting,
Henry

Answer (score 0):

Shoe polish and anything else creamy/pasty will not penetrate enough, unless perhaps melted.  Needs to be something liquid and fine.  Search "black leather dye."  Four oz. runs about $5.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a dye, it should work, but your best bet is to go to a professional for the job.  However, they are quite expensive, and you could be better off getting new shoes.  I suggest the dye.  It really works after a few coats.